# Space seprated values to ndarray

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, data-analysis

I am trying to have a data set imported for my machine learning model.
Data is of images stored as values of pixels of each image.
Image size is 48X48.
I need to convert this to ndarray but as its space separated so

`X = data[:, 1].reshape(data.shape[0],1,48, 48).astype( 'float32' )`

doesn't work.
I need help in converting this data to ndarray of(nX48X48).(n->no. of rows.)
EDIT:-
I tried,

```
`data=pd.read_csv('../input/fer2013.csv').values
X=data[:,1]
for i in range(len(X)):
       X[i]=np.asarray(X[i].split(" "),dtype=np.float32)
       X[i]=X[i].reshape(1,48,48).astype('float32')`
```

It does not change shape of column.
I wish the shape of X to be(n,1,48,48)
But doing above keeps the shape to be(n).[sample row of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ss7Yk.png)

Format of data:
[pixels column of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAEZl.png)

Thanks and regards,

Comment: is it a text file?

Comment: If it's space-separated, you probably want [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). You may have to fiddle with the arguments to match your exact format, but it sounds like you may just have the default format (newline-separated rows or whitespace-separated columns with no quoting).

Comment: @sacul its a csv file.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from your description, it seems that the columns are space separated and the rows are newline separated.  If this is the case, then you can use Numpy's [`genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) method.

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt(f, delimiter=' ')
```

If you've already got the space-newline-separated mess read in as a string `string_data`, you need to split it into lines first:

```
f = string_data.split('\n')
```

From your link it seems you can just pass in the `data["pixels"]` Series, possibly.